# how to get files list in a folder with batch file without file extensions

Tags: script, batch-file

What I used is below and its perfect but results are with file extension.(ABC123.pdf)

```
dir /a /b /-p/o:gen >C:\WINDOWS\Temp\file_list
start notepad C:\WINDOWS\Temp\file_list
```

I need results without file extension just a file name (ABC123)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension

Comment: @Dave renaming files is not the OP's aim, imho. This is the question of file names _display_ only. See Optichip's comment.

Answer (score 0):

if exist c:\Windows\Temp\files.txt del c:\Windows\Temp\file_list

for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /a /b /-p/o:gen') do echo %%~nj >> c:\Windows\Temp\file_list

start notepad C:\WINDOWS\Temp\file_list

Adapted from http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/listing-files-without-thier-extensions-batch/24325.html